# Visual Studio won't open C# projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, project

Starting from yesterday, whenever I try to open a C# project (.csproj) in visual studio 

I get this 3 times:
[image]

And then I get this 1 time:
[image]
And thus it doesn't open the project.
This doesn't appear when opening C++ or VB projects, only C#
I have tried running the application with parameters like /resetsettings and /resetskippkgs  but it didn't do.

Please help me solve the problem

Comment: Was it working before or you have this problem from the beginning?

Comment: Reinstall Visual Studio

Comment: Did you check the `ActivityLog.xml` mentioned in the error (after starting VS with the `/log` parameter, also mentioned)?

Comment: Create new project with source files from previous one.

Comment: Running the REPAIR might fix the problem.

Comment: Did you try "running the application together with the /log parameter on the command line, and then examining the file D:\[...]ActivityLog.xml"?

Comment: Dilshod: It worked for a month, but Yesterday it stopped working. --
Oded: Yes though I haven't found much info --
praks411: I haddn't mentioned! Even the previous projects I have created cannot be loaded

Comment: It looks like your C# Template files corrupt. I suggest to run Repair to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reinstall VS.
2. Try to open another project and see if you can open it, if it opens, copy the source files to the new project and continue as usually.
3. What version of VS are u using?

Comment: so I am suggesting to move to vs 2012, faster and has far less bugs.

Comment: Perhaps. I'll see if I can do anything more before the full reinstallation.

Answer (score 1):

Your Visual Studio install has become corrupted. Reinstall Visual Studio ("Repair" should work ) and it should fix itself.